# onRightButtonPress React Native undefined is not an object NavigatorIOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator-ios

### Here There

I have a problem with my React Native code, i am new in React programming, so cannot read the errors correct :-(

Hopefully someone can help

```
export default class NavigationBar extends Component {

_handleNavigationRequest = () => {
    this.refs.nav.push({
        component: Settings,
        title: 'Genius',
        passProps: { myProp: 'genius' },
    });
}



render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS barTintColor='#50C26B' titleTextColor='#fff' tintColor='#fff'
            initialRoute={{
                component: Genius,
                title: 'Happy Genius',
                rightButtonTitle: 'Add',
                onRightButtonPress: () => this._handleNavigationRequest(),
            }}
            style={style.navBarStyle}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Got the error: undefined is noch an object (evaluating 'this.refs.nav.push') 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the ref parameter in your NavigatorIOS

```
render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS ref='nav' 
            barTintColor='#50C26B' titleTextColor='#fff' tintColor='#fff'
            initialRoute={{
                component: Genius,
                title: 'Happy Genius',
                rightButtonTitle: 'Add',
                onRightButtonPress: () => this._handleNavigationRequest(),
            }}
            style={style.navBarStyle}
        />
    );
  }
```

Comment: oh, thanks a lot (Y), such an dam mistake, made my day :-)